# API description with queryparameter per API call in RAML

Tags: api, raml

I have to describe an old API with RAML and i'm struggling with the syntax.
Due time issues we have to keep the old API calls.

I'm trying to describe the following calls:

`?Call=GetData&suuid=1234567
    ?Call=AddNewData&dataid=12345suuid=1234567
    ?Call=DeleteData&dataid=12345suuid=1234567`

Is that possible with RAML?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: I assume there's a missing `&` before `suuid` on lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this in RAML but you won't be able to define different responses for each of the different `Call` values.

What you can do though is use the `anyOf` construct of JSON Schema `draft-4` to specify the different valid responses applicable to this single resource.